# Admob Integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, admob

Could any one helpme with how to add admob codes in Appdelegate file.
Currently i have the following code in my appdelegate file.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{


        [web_online loadHTMLString:@"<h1>Loading...</h1>" baseURL:nil];
    current_word = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"keyword"];
    current_url = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
#if 0
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"auto_correction"] == NO)
        search_main.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
    else
        search_main.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

#endif
    //search_main.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    search_main.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    search_main.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

    [self init_data];
    [self init_sound];
    [window addSubview:nav_main.view];
    [window addSubview:view_start];

#ifdef DISABLE_ADMOB
    view_ad.hidden = YES;
#endif

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

My question is how to add the admob codes ie the code below

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height -
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

  // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
  bannerView_.adUnitID = @"67576511260";

  // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
  // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
  bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
  [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

  // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
  [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

in the appdelegate file. 
Everything else i have done.
All my code is done in appdelegate file . ie why this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two questions to answer here.

Firstly, just put the code before the `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` replacing instances of `[self view]` with `window` and it should work.

Secondly, why is all that in your app delegate? The standard way of writing iPhone apps is to use a UIViewController with UIView objects (apple's variant on MVC) - this separates out your data and presentation code nicely.

More importantly here, all libraries like this will assume that you've used this pattern - hence you are finding trouble getting the admob code to work - it's designed to fit inside a UIViewController, not inside an app delegate.

Why have you decided not to use view controllers?